# Declare Variable and concat all values of a select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am used to write queries in Sql Server and Oracle but new to MySql. I need to declare a variable and set all the values in a select statement. Here is what I am trying,

```
set @v = '' 
select @v = @v + column from table group by column
select @v
```

If column have

```
column
------
  a
  a
  c
```

Then the query should return,

```
  @v
  --
  ac
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select @v := group_concat(distinct column SEPARATOR '')
from table;
```

**Result:**

```
| @v  |
| --- |
| ac  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEZVBdGupfkzLTRMvU1Hzd/0)

Comment: Nice. How do I see the contents of @v. Select @v not working

Comment: weird running together showing error. Running one at a time showing only one value. In shot not working

Comment: @user960567 This answer should work for you. Check this DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEZVBdGupfkzLTRMvU1Hzd/0

Comment: I don't know why its starting to work with distinct but thanks